# Liskov Substitution Principle with multiple inheritance heirachies

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

I am trying to come up with an object oriented design, and having difficulty satisfying the Liskov Substitution Principle. Here is an illustrative example:

```
class Food
{
    public:
    virtual void printName() {
    //......
    }
};
class Fruit : public Food
{
};
class Meat : public Food
{
};
class Animal
{
    public:
    Food *_preferredFood;
    virtual void setFoodPreference(Food *food)=0;

};
class Carnivore: public Animal
{
    public:
    void setFoodPreference(Food *food) {
        this->_preferredFood = dynamic_cast<Meat *>(food);
    }
};
class Herbivore: public Animal
{
    public:
    void setFoodPreference(Food *food) {
        this->_preferredFood = dynamic_cast<Fruit *>(food);
    }
};
```

How can I enforce the following:

1. Each subclass of Animal should allow setting a food preference, without breaking LSP
2. The food preference for each derived class of animal is a subclass of Food

Fore example, if somebody extends `Animal` to create `MarineMammal`, the food preference might be `Fish` (which they will create by extending `Food`).

Comment: out of interest, what is the actual polymorphic behaviour you're looking for? i.e. what exact methods will client code be calling against the base class? I ask this because I think you risk solving the wrong problem. Animals may *look at first glance* like an inheritance problem, but it's more likely to be a traits problem in reality.

Comment: You're right, I am not looking for polymorphic behavior. What I really want is for anybody who extend ``Animal`` to define the right ``setFoodPreference`` function. Of course I could argue that I want to call ``setFoodPreference``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Carnivore::setFoodPreference` only accepts `Meat` and `Herbivore::setFoodPreference` only accepts `Fruit`, then they do not comply to the same contract. That means they are not actually the same method. When you call this method, you have to know if you are dealing with a carnivore or a herbivore to avoid passing the wrong type. When you forget to check this, you risk creating a bug which manifests in form of a casting error at runtime.

The solution is to separate these two methods.

I would recommend you to remove `setFoodPreference` from the public interface and instead add methods `Carnivore::setMeatPreference(Meat *meat)` and `Herbivore::setFruitPreference(Fruit *fruit)` directly to the subclasses. That way any code which sets the food preference must know what kind of Animal and what kind of Food it is dealing with, so you can no longer write code which tries to set an incompatible food type.

Internally, both methods may set a `protected Food *_preferredFood` from the common base class. Or even better, call a `protected void setPreferredFood(Food *food)` which is a setter for a `private Food* _preferredFood`. That variable should definitely not be public to ensure proper encapsulation.

Comment: I think I should keep _preferredFood private, and make setFoodPreference protected virtual. Because I need to enforce that the derived classes allow for the preference to be set.

Comment: @user2308211 why `virtual`? When any subclasses call that method only through their own methods, you can put any code specific to the subclass there.

Comment: I should've said, purely virtual. To make sure they implement these methods. Although it's not a complete solution, somebody could derive from Animal, and implement only setFoodPreference.

Comment: marking as unanswered, to invite further responses.