# Liskov substitution principle and multiple hierarchies

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

This question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268558/liskov-substitution-principle-with-multiple-inheritance-heirachies/). I am trying to define class heirarchies involving multiple base-derived pairs. As an illustrative example, suppose that I have a class `Animal` and a class `Food`. `Animal` has a pure virtual function to mark its food preference, taking a food as parameter.

```
class Food
{
    public:
    virtual void printName() {
    //......
    }
};

class Animal
{
    public:
    Food *_preferredFood;
    virtual void setFoodPreference(Food *food)=0;

};
```

I need to write code that deals only with these base classes, and calls the pure virtual function. For example, I have a `ZooManager` class, which sets food preferences for each animal.

```
class ZooManager
{
    vector<Aninal*> animals;
    public:
    void setAllPreferences(vector<Food *> foods) {
        assert(animals.size() == foods.size());
        for(int i =0;i<animals.size();i++) {
            animals[i]->setFoodPreference(foods[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

So far so good. Now the problem is, that there are many different derived classes for `Food` and `Animal`. `Food` has derived classes `Fruit` and `Meat`, and `Animal` has derived classes `Carnivore` and `Herbivore`. `Herbivore` can accept only `Fruit` as food preference, and `Carnivore` can accept only `Meat`.

```
class Fruit : public Food
{
};
class Meat : public Food
{
};
class Carnivore: public Animal
{
    public:
    void setFoodPreference(Food *food) {
    this->_preferredFood = dynamic_cast<Meat *>(food);
    }
};
class Herbivore: public Animal
{
    public:
    void setFoodPreference(Food *food) {
    this->_preferredFood = dynamic_cast<Fruit *>(food);
    }
};
```

Can I create a class heirarchy for this without violating Liskov Substitution Principle? Although I use C++ in this question, I'd welcome Java-specific answers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `setFoodPreference` has to have the option to *fail*.  That lets `setFoodPreference` take a `Food*` and have the postcondition of either setting the food preference, or failing.

The dynamic cast can also be a failure of LSP, but if you arrange your type invariants to be vague enough it isn't technically a failure.

Generally, `dynamic_cast` means that the type of the argument passed and its properties isn't sufficient to tell if the argument has certain properties.

In principle, `setFoodPreference(Food*)` should be specified in terms of what `Food*` properties the passed in argument has to have in order for the setting to be successful; the dynamic type of the `Food*` is not a `Food*` property.

So: LSP states that any subclass of `Food` has to obey all `Food` invariants.  Similarly for `Animal`.  You can avoid a LSP violation by making the invariants vague and the behavior of methods unpredictable; basically by saying "it can fail for unspecified reasons".  This is ... not very satisfying.

Now, you can take a step back and decide that the dynamic type of your `Food*` is *part* of the `Food*`'s interface; that makes the interface ridiculously broad, and makes a mockery of LSP.

The point of LSP is that you can reason about a `Food*` without having to think about its subclass types; they are "how it works as a `Food`".  Your code binds tightly to the subclass types, and thus bypasses the point of LSP.

There are ways around this.  If `Food` had an enum stating what kind of food it was, and you never dynamically cast down to `Meat` but rather asked the `Food` if it was meat, you avoid it.  Now you can specify `setFoodPreference`'s behavior in terms of `Food`'s interface.

Comment: I don't like the enum solution primarily because it is so often used to abuse OO programming, essentially putting child class information in a base class. I've seen code where `Base` has an enum for `Type` with values `CHILD1, CHILD2, CHILD3` etc. Which then encourages a bunch of code to accept a `Base*`, and then proceed to check the underlying type. Such code is reflective of someone thinking they can get all the benefits of polymorphism with none of the drawbacks. `dynamic_cast`ing away is not much better, either.

Comment: @AndyG I didn't say it was a *great* solution; but as written above, each Animal kind cares about what Food kind it gets.  Basically, the abstraction behind the Food class *leaks*, because Food is a pretty useless abstraction; abstracting handling raw meat the same way you handle hay is a very questionable thing to do.

Comment: Agreed. I think OP has architected themselves into a corner. My comment was not intended to disagree with you, but reinforce why the "solutions" to OPs problem are not desirable.

Comment: We haven't started any kind of implementation, which is why I want a good design to work on. The issue here is that while I write the base-classes, the derived classes are written by teams all over the world, and we don't even know how many we might have. But there is a definite coupling between derived classes of ``Animal`` and derived classes of ``Food``. My immediate concern right now is how I could write ``ZooManager``.

Comment: @user2308211 Suppose you where writing a system which lets clients plug-in a scripting system.  They provide scripts and variable value holders, and you set up a way for the app to hook up scripts and save them and run them and load the library (maybe from the 'net) and the resources etc.  All of these *details* might provide a solution that an abstract question about LSP and food/animal types won't, even though they both have LSP problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to designing your hierarchies is wrong. OO classes represent groups of tightly coupled rules, where a rule is a function and tightly coupled means shared data. OO classes do NOT represent real world objects. People are wrong when they say that.

If you are depending on the concrete type of Food, you are violating the Liskov substitution principle. Period.

To design your classes correctly so that you are not forced into violating the LSP as you are here, you need to place rules in the Food class that can be used by the Animal class to accomplish its own rules. Or decide whether Food should even be a class. What your example shows is basically really bad String comparison.